# Reinstall Project Server 2007 and use existing databases

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-project

I had a hdd failure and right now I'm reinstalling a new machine with MOSS and Project Server, in a farm configuration. All the databases of the former farm were on another machine that runs SQL Server. How can I set my new machine to use the existing databases and preserver all of my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call Microsoft support.  I went through this once and it was totally hairy.

If you're dealing with a production outage, this is pretty much always good advice.  Posting a question on a site like ServerFault is a great way to get advice, but if your servers are down, time is of the essence and advice quality is of the essence.  You don't have the time to wait for the community to build and choose the best answer, especially not for something intricate like this.